# Can I in Thunder Client plugin of Visual studio code to sort items at left panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Thunder Client plugin in Visual studio code  to test my api site.

Having some activity lines I wonder if there is a way to sort them by “AUTH”, “CRUD” groups ?

[image]

I tried to search some options for dragging of elements in left side but failed.

Thunder Client v2.17.1
Visual studio code : 1.85.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the requests to collections which can be ordered by dragging and dropping.

Example:

[image: initial-collection]

[image: ordered-collection]